# How to store data without using much space at c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, storage, bitset

i am using c++, i need to store 6 boolean data without passing over 8 bits of space usage. And i need store them by using an array-like stuff ( vector, array, matrix etc. ). Some methods like vector uses much data than it's elements. I need to save on data storage, which method should i use?

Comment: Use [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: It's not C++ but it uses less 'space' as you call it. Just use a `char` and you are only using 8-bit. Less than this is not possible in my point of view, because everything lesser than will be aligned internally to 8 bit at least.

Comment: U think so ckruczek..? I hoped i can find a way to store with less than 8 bits. In fact it shouldnt be in c++ at all. All computer opportunities are fine for me. U know someway for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store 6 bools with using only 8 bits (1 byte), you can only do it manually with storing them in unsigned char. `std::vector<bool>` ([std::vector bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)) indeed uses bit packing to store bools, but it adds about 20 bytes overhead in other members and virtual functions. `std::bitset` ([std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)) store bits packet but in 4-byte increments, you'll have 3 bytes overhead to store 1 byte.

Comment: So, to store 6 bit by bitset i need to give storage of 24 bits? If it is true that's so much, arent there a more saving way to do it?

Comment: @user6551379 you can store 6 bits in 1 byte by using a single unsigned char (1 byte) and writing all the functions by yourself. If you want to utilize standard library, there will be overhead.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` isn't really recommendable IMO. `std::bitset` is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::bitset` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to store just one bit per bool or you can use `std::vector<bool>` which is defined to use a bit per bool internally.

Comment: bitset is templated on the number of elements, how can vector be defined as bitset internally?

Comment: Ok, not a bitset specifically, but "one bit per bool".

Comment: But isn't vector<bool> itself uses extra data expect it's elements? Will a vector<bool>v(6) use just 6 bits?

Comment: Thanks for bitset i'll search it

Comment: @user6551379 bitset stores bits in 4 byte increments. sizeof(std::bitset<6>) == 4, and you can't to much about it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bitset class (in C++ standard library).

This is a snippet how to use it:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::bitset<6> bitarray;    // [0,0,0,0,0,0]

  bitarray.set(3, true)       // [0,0,0,1,0,0]

  if (bitarray.test(3) == true) { // Yeah is true!
     std::cout << "The fourth bit is true\n";
  }
}
```

In that way you should use only 6 bit.

Answer (score -1):

if you can't use more than 8 bits you can use a `char`. you can use each bit as a bool - 1 if true, 0 if false:

```
char my_bool = 0;
if(condition_1 == TRUE)
    my_bool |= 1;
else
    my_bool &= 0b11111110;
if(condition_2 == TRUE)
    my_bool |= 2;
else
    my_bool &= 0b11111101;
if(condition_3 == TRUE)
    my_bool |= 4;
else
    my_bool &= 0b11111011;
```

and so on...

Comment: This is a poor and error prone solution when std::bitset is available.

Comment: @Borgleader I wasn't familiar with std::bitset, thx. BTW, if can't use std::bitset - would this still be a bad solution?

Comment: What |= and &= means, i googled it but couldnt find anything? Btw it looks like a nice way

Comment: @user6551379 these are bitwise operations. my_bool |= 4 should turn the 3rd bit to 1, while my_bool &= 0b11111011 should turn it to 0

Comment: BTW, the `char` type is not guaranteed to be `unsigned` nor 8 bits.  You want to use `uint8_t`, which is guaranteed to be 8 bits.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews hmm thank you, it looks nice. But if possible i want to spend less than 8 bits in fact. Can i identify something like uint7_t which should be 7 bits?

Comment: Most popular computers have a minimum unit of 8 bits.  There are some {embedded} processors that have bit addressable memory.  If you really want to pack bits, you should use a ratio that is a multiple of 8.  So for example, if you are only storing 6 bits, you should store 4 groups among 3 bytes.

Comment: BTW, bit manipulation tends to slow down the performance of processors.  Processors love to use their word size (16-bits, 3-bits, 64-bits, et. al.).  They get upset when told to use unconventional sizes (such as 6 or 24-bits).  There really is no benefit in trying to use only 6 bits when a processor is more efficient with 8 bits (wasting 2 bits is not a crime an may speed up execution).  As far as memory space, most applications won't notice (what's 2 bits wasted out of 1 gigabyte?).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews but char must have enough bits for 95 different values - at least 7 bits, and that would be enough here, will it not? also, why does signed/unsigned matter? (I can use bit masks instead of |= 4 to make sure that the right bit is set)